# Should "what should I do" with an answer of "consult a lawyer" be closed as a legal question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, legal-questions

I saw [Employer wants me to write down "I accept the termination" on my termination paper](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/94232/employer-wants-me-to-write-down-i-accept-the-termination-on-my-termination-pap) was closed as being a legal question.

Now the question itself doesn't ask "is this legal", which would obviously be a legal question that has no place here. The question is more "what should I do", which seems on topic, even if the answer might come down to "consult a lawyer" (at least partly).

My argument is as follows: how should someone know if they need to consult a lawyer? Isn't it reasonable to not know that this is a situation where a lawyer needs to be consulted, thus making it a reasonable not-so-legal workplace question (even if the answer is somewhat in another castle)?

Comment: I agree, it should not have been closed. VTRO

Comment: FYI, it has been reopened

Answer (score 3):

As the one who asked the question I think it's important that comments like "consult a lawyer" are handled neutral for those two reasons:

- Maybe the one who asked the question doesn't even realizes how bad
  the situation is and that a lawyer is needed
- Depending on the country speaking to a lawyer costs you to much for
  such cases - in my country you can expect about 1500$ costs for the first hour of talking to a lawyer. Often then you rethink that idea.

It shouldn't get closed as legal question but - if needed - as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Closing a question based the answers it may generate has merit when it comes to obviously opinion-based or direct-legal questions. However, if a question could legitimately generate other types of answers as well, I don't see why a questions should be closed based on its answers.